# Linux equivalent of clip.exe

Tags: linux, clipboard

I am trying to figure out how to copy the contents of a file to and from the clipboard in Linux (Ubuntu Server 11.10, bash). Is there a linux equvalent of the Windows command `clip < filename`? If so, what is it? In addition, the server does not have a GUI.

I have heard of such packages as `xsel` and `xclip`, but I was hoping to find something that does not require additional packages to be installed. If this is not possible, what are the advantages and disadvantages of each of the above packages? Are there other packages with the same purpose? If so, what are their advantages and disadvantages?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Practically *everything* in Linux comes in the form of "additional packages" – usually shared libraries which are written once and used in hundreds of programs to avoid needless duplication. You shouldn't be afraid of them unless you are *critically* low on disk space.

However, Linux itself does not have a "clipboard"; this function is part of the X11 graphical interface. Both `xsel` and `xclip` require X11 to work – it does not have to be on the *server* (which only needs libX11 and xauth, nothing more); if you are connecting over SSH, X11 can be running on your desktop; but you still need the X11 display *somewhere*.

```
local$ ls | xsel -i
local$ ssh -Y myserver
myserver$ xsel -o > list.txt
```

(In this example, `ssh -Y` enables X11-over-SSH, allowing you to run X11 programs on the server and have them connect to the local X11 display. The differences between `xsel` and `xclip` are very minimal, their core functionality is same.)

If you are working at the console, in a text-only tty, these tools won't work. You will have to use something like `gpm` or `screen` or `tmux` instead – `gpm` works by adding mouse support to the tty's, while `screen` and `tmux` both are "terminal multiplexers" which only have the clipboard as a secondary feature (but are nevertheless useful, allowing tiling of multiple terminals in one tty).

Comment: In response to your comment about differences between `xclip` and `xsel`, `xclip` seems better at handling large amounts of text than `xsel`, in my experience, but Tkinter's built-in copy seems to handle large amounts of text better than either. I'm not sure why. (Although Tkinter's built-in copy won't handle all Unicode characters like xclip will.)